# How to print byte array in IE 11 using angular 7

Tags: angular, internet-explorer

I'm getting the byte array from backend and converting it into blob and trying to print it.

Here's my code:

```
    const byteArr = this.convertbase64toArrayBuffer(this.PDFResponse.fileContent);

    const blob = new Blob([byteArr], { type: 'application/pdf' });

    const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

    iframe.style.display = 'none';

    iframe.src = blobUrl;

    document.body.appendChild(iframe);

    iframe.contentWindow.document.body.focus();

    iframe.contentWindow.print();
```

This works perfectly in Chrome, but not working in IE.

I know `iframe.src` doesn't works in IE, but is there any way I can print my blob file in IE ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE doesn't have pdf previewer installed inside of it, so it's impossible to display PDF directly in IE. So I think we can't print it directly in IE.

A workaround is saving it in IE then print it manually. IE has its own API for creating and downloading files, which is called `msSaveOrOpenBlob`. You could use the code like below:

```
var blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/pdf' });
if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {  //if IE
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob);
}
else {
    var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    ...
}
```

Besides, you could try [PDF.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) to parse and render PDFs. It uses a link like this to show PDFs:

```
http://your_webserver_address/your_PDFjs_foldername/web/viewer.html?file=your_pdf_address
```

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response.